# SoapUI Free - Groovy Script in Property Value to Get TestSuite Property

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I am using the free (non-PRO) SoapUI 5.0 and I have a list of properties in a Test Suite.
I then have a number of Test Steps, each one having the same name as a Test Suite property.

I'm trying to write Groovy script in a Test Step property to retrieve the value of the Test Suite property with the same name.

For example:

- Test Suite has a property **colour_red** with the value 12345.
- Within the Test Suite is a Test Case, with a Test Step also called *colour_red*.
- Within the *colour_red* Test Step is a property "info".
- I'm trying to get the property value for "info" to be the Test Suite
  property **colour_red** value of 12345.

What I have so far in the "info" property value:

```
${=new GroovyShell().evaluate(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue(context.getCurrentStep().getLabel()))}
```

I'm not sure if I need the **new GroovyShell().evaluate** bit, but without that it still doesn't work. I cannot tell exactly what is being picked up but it is not the value of the Test Suite property with the same name.

From what I can see the script should retrieve the current Test Step name (*colour_red*) and then look for a property called that in the Test Suite.

My reason for doing this is that I have data in the Test Suite property values which needs to be shared between numerous Test Cases (all with many Test Steps).
Without the PRO version I am struggling but I think with Groovy there should be a way to do this.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think researching property expansion will help you. 
http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html

To get you going...

You can easily reference property values using these dynamic references:

Put a reference like `${#TestSuite#colour_red}` as the property value of "info".

Now the info property value is dynamicaly set to whatever the TestSuite's colour_red property value is.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using ${#TestSuite#colour_red} however I wanted to be able to use the same value for every TestCase in the TestSuite instead of having to alter each one
  e.g. ${#TestSuite#colour_blue}, ${#TestSuite#colour_green}.
  But looking at the Property Expansion link I spotted my issue and have now used Groovy script as follows:
  ${#TestSuite#${=context.getCurrentStep().getLabel()}}
  
  This means I can put the same property value in every TestStep.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
def myStep = context.currentStep.name
def myValue = context.expand( '${#Project#' + myStep + '}' )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("info", myValue)
```

I made it a little more verbose than it needs to be. I do not think that -Pro will help you, unless I misunderstood what you need.

Comment: Thanks @SiKing - however would a multiple line script be possible in a single property value? I have resolved this now but interested to know if larger scripts are possible.

Comment: Like I said: I made this more verbose than it needs to be. You can combine the above into a one-liner: `${=testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('info', context.expand( '${#Project#' + context.currentStep.name + '}' ))}`; careful of nested quotes.